# Procedural Terrain Computing Normal in Shader

Tags: shaders, lighting

I've been pulling my hair out on this. I'm trying to paint a procedural terrain.

The white ball in this photo is supposed to be the light source. However, it looks like it is shining black light.

The terrain's y position vertex are determined via a `fx(x,y,z)` function. So basically `fx(x,y,z)` goes to `x,y',z`.

To paint proper lighting, I am trying to compute the normals via a method I read about online where you determine the slope of positions in the x and z direction and then use cross product to determine the normal vector.

```
vec3 getNormal(vec3 p) {
            float offset=0.01;
            vec3 neighbor1 = vec3(p.x-offset,p.y,p.z);
            vec3 neighbor2 = vec3(p.x,p.y,p.z-offset);
            neighbor1.y = fx(neighbor1);
            neighbor2.y = fx(neighbor2);
            p.y = fx(p);
            vec3 tangent = neighbor1-p;
            vec3 bitangent = neighbor2-p;
            return normalize(cross(tangent,bitangent));
        }
```

I pass in the world position for each vertex point and assign it to the normal for the fragment shader `vnormal`. And then I paint via this method:

```
        vec3 lightColor = vec3(1.,1.,1.);
        vec3 lightPos = lightSource;
        vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPos - vposition);
        float lightIntensity = clamp(dot(vnormal, lightDir),0.,1.);
        vec3 col = vec3(lightIntensity);
```

Where is my math wrong?

[image]

Comment: Does the result look any more plausible if you negate the normal? (Say, flipping the order of the cross product, or using `+ offset` instead of `- offset`, or `p - neighbour` rather than `neightbour - p`)

Comment: Whoa. Switching the cross product parameters seemed to do the trick. Jeez I feel silly now.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, post your solution as an answer below.  For a little context, if you're using a left-handed coordinate system of x+ right, y+ up, z+ forward, then the tangent you've calculated here points left and your bitangent points back. Orient your left hand so that your fingers point left and curl back, and your thumb will point downward, indicating that the normal you form this way points down instead of up. Inverting the order flips that.